# Join values of multiple arrays where the keys are identical into one giant array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 different arrays with the a constant (but unknown) number of items.

```
$array1 = array("orange", "banana", "plum");
$array2 = array("apple", "raspberry", "pineapple");
$array3 = array("kiwi", "tomato", "lemon");
```

I want to join the values of each array where the keys are identical into one giant array. The array I'm looking to create is below.

```
$desired_array = array("orange,apple,kiwi", "banana,raspberry,tomato", "plum,pineapple,lemon");
```

I'm not even entirely sure how to approach this. I tried

```
foreach ($array1 as $arr1) {
    foreach ($array2 as $arr2) {
        foreach ($array3 as $arr3) {
            $arr .= $arr1 . "," . $arr2 . "," . $arr3 ."\n";
        }
    }
}
```

But that returns

```
orange,apple,kiwi
orange,apple,tomato
orange,apple,lemon
orange,raspberry,kiwi
orange,raspberry,tomato
orange,raspberry,lemon
orange,pineapple,kiwi
orange,pineapple,tomato
orange,pineapple,lemon
banana,apple,kiwi
banana,apple,tomato
banana,apple,lemon
banana,raspberry,kiwi
banana,raspberry,tomato
banana,raspberry,lemon
banana,pineapple,kiwi
banana,pineapple,tomato
banana,pineapple,lemon
plum,apple,kiwi
plum,apple,tomato
plum,apple,lemon
plum,raspberry,kiwi
plum,raspberry,tomato
plum,raspberry,lemon
plum,pineapple,kiwi
plum,pineapple,tomato
plum,pineapple,lemon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution **ASSUMING length of the array's is always same**.

```
<?php

   $array1 = array("orange", "banana", "plum");
   $array2 = array("apple", "raspberry", "pineapple");
   $array3 = array("kiwi", "tomato", "lemon");

   $arr=array();
   for($l=0;$l<count($array1);$l++)
   {
       $arr[$l]=$array1[$l].",".$array2[$l].",".$array3[$l];
   }

   print_r($arr);
   /*o/p:Array ( [0] => orange,apple,kiwi [1] => banana,raspberry,tomato [2] => plum,pineapple,lemon )*/

?>
```

EDIT:

In case you need it,in a **FOR EACH** Loop

```
<?php

    $array1 = array("orange", "banana", "plum");
    $array2 = array("apple", "raspberry", "pineapple");
    $array3 = array("kiwi", "tomato", "lemon");

    $arr2=array();
    foreach($array1 as $key=>$value) 
    {
        $arr2[$key]=$array1[$key].",".$array2[$key].",".$array3[$key];
    }

    print_r($arr2);
?>
```